# Android: Change src alpha and keep background (blend src with color)

Tags: android, imagebutton, alpha

I've been looking for this for a while but can't really figure out any clean way to do it.

I'm developing an app with some buttons, mostly defined like this:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/btn1" />
```

There's a `onTouchListener` that changes the button alpha with `setAlpha(0.5f)`, but it also changes the background alpha, which is not what I need. I'd like to make it look darker, not trasparent.

I've seen this question: [Android Graphics: Changing the alpha of just an image (not the background)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840575/android-graphics-changing-the-alpha-of-just-an-image-not-the-background), and the solution actually works, but it doesn't sound good for me to create a `FrameLayout` for every button in my app.

Given the fact that the background is a flat color I thought there would be a simpler solution such as color blending or something like that, but really couldn't find it anywhere.

**SOLUTION**

Just found out this post: http://tech.chitgoks.com/2011/04/17/android-change-imagebutton-tint-to-simulate-button-pressed/

The solution is as simple as:

```
button.setColorFilter(Color.argb(150,0,0,0));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get image drawable using `getDrawable()` method and try to change its alpha.

Comment: Thanks, it actually did the trick. But what if my buttons are round-shaped? Is there any way to make them darker without a big black square behind?